# How to make visualforce email template fields populate?

Tags: visualforce, email, process-builder, process, alert

I have tested a visualforce email template using the "Send Test and Verify Merge Fields" option of the email editor and the fields populate with information from the referenced record when I do so. When I have the email auto-send upon record creation via a process from process builder, however, some of the custom fields on the object do not populate in the email while other fields do. I have checked the user permissions on the fields--any ideas what the solution might be?

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="2017 Annual Conference Submission" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="EventApi__Speaker__c"   >
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >

Thank you for your submission to the {!relatedTo.EventApi__Event__r.EventApi__Display_Name__c}. Below is a copy of the     information submitted for your records.

Submission ID: {!relatedTo.CaseSafeID__c}

Title: {!relatedTo.Session_Title__c}

Program Type: {!relatedTo.Session_Type__c}

Target Audience: {!relatedTo.Target_Audience_s__c}

Learning Outcome 1: {!relatedTo.Learning_Outcome_1__c}
Learning Outcome 2: {!relatedTo.Learning_Outcome_2__c}
Learning Outcome 3: {!relatedTo.Learning_Outcome_3__c}

Topic(s): {!relatedTo.Session_Topic_s__c}

Abstract: {!relatedTo.Session_Abstract__c}

Primary Presenter:
Title: {!relatedTo.EventApi__Title__c}
Name: {!relatedTo.Name}
Institution/Company: {!relatedTo.EventApi__Company_Name__c}
Email: {!relatedTo.EventApi__Email__c}
Phone 1: {!relatedTo.EventApi__Phone__c}
Phone 2: {!relatedTo.EventApi__Other_Phone__c}
Biography: {!relatedTo.EventApi__Bio__c}


You will be notified of the status of your submission the week of March 27.

</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you share some of the code here?

Comment: What are those some fields. Are these fields belong to specific namespace or random?

Comment: Some fields are from a managed object whereas others are custom-created by users.